# PHP get INT from angular http request

Tags: php, angularjs

**How to get an int-value from an $http-request in PHP ?**

I´m trying to send a http request from an Angular app  but i´m not able to get the value of the sent `id`` parameter into my PHP variable $id.

I tried several methods like:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

or

```
$id = $connection->real_escape_string(isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] :'');
```

in my PHP but nothing works...

This is my function to send the $http request

```
function removeFriend( id ) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "delete",
            url: "php/deleteFriend.php",data: $.param({'id':id}),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
        return( request.then( handleSuccess, handleError ) );
    }
```

Comment: because you're doing an http delete. therefore PHP won't populate $_POST, which is  only done when you use the `post` verb...

Comment: Start by looking at the request in your browser's debugger tools. How exactly is the request sent? Does it contain body data? Perhaps the id is sent as a query parameter in the URL instead?

Comment: @MarcB Thank you, it works now. Maybe you can add an answer so I can accept it ;)

Comment: it would be nice if you could post your solution if others have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the method of the $http request. you have to use `POST` so PHP can get the values with the `$_POST['id']` method.

So here is the code that works:

**Javascript**

```
function removeFriend( id ) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "php/deleteFriend.php",data: $.param({'id':id}),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
        return( request.then( handleSuccess, handleError ) );
    }
```

**PHP**

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make your request like this :

```
function removeAccount(id) {
  var request = $http({
    method: "DELETE",
    url: urlBase,
    data: {
      id: id
    }
  });

  return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));

}
```

also you please add at your config angular this code :

```
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {
        if (data === undefined) {
            return data;
        }
        return $.param(data);
    };
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
```

Mine working and hope it helps

Comment: I guess this one doesn´t work out for me due to the `method: 'DELETE'`. See my answer for a working solution.

Comment: @JohnDizzle, Well for me it is working, I just add the $httpProvider config to my config angular, if you don't add the config It doesnt work, and PHP wont detect the request.